# Remove category(Top menu) for specific customer or customer group

Tags: magento-1.9, toplinks, topmenu

I m using magento 1.9.0.1 to remove cateogroy from frontend top menu for specific category for specific customer or customer group.
I m using below code for testing but it not work

```
/frontend/default/YOURTHEMENAME/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml

    <?php $_menu = ''?>
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
    <?php $_menu .= $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php if ($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
    <?php if (!in_array($_category->getId(), array(12,34,56))) : ?> <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: you can fetch the data using customer session and based on that you can show and hide the menu

Comment: i know that but i m creating one extenssion so it should be compatible to magento version so i mean which block override to customize top menu or any event for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Freedom,you can get current customer group below code

`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()` from session you need put code

Comment: i know but which code block override for top menu customisatio or any event that i can listen and do whatever i need.

Comment: this phtml file is rebnder from Mage_Catalog_Block_Naviagtion class

Comment: wait . i will give solution

Comment: peploes downvote for you also, crazy guys.....

Answer (score 0):

```
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId() //to get customer id

$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); //to get customer group id



<?php if (!in_array(customerId, array(10,20,30))) : ?> //the costumers id that you want to remove the category
      // Your category block
<?php endif;?>
```

The same thing for customer group